# Agora Cloud Recording doesn't record mixed in audio files

Tags: agora.io

Hi I have been successfully recording an Agora audio call, where one person speaks in a broadcast role, and during the call mixes in a number of audio files.

All the audio was being recorded until we upgraded to flutter 2 and associated upgraded packages.

Now all that is recorded is the broadcaster voice, and no mixed in audio.

The broadcaster and audience members can all hear the mixed in audio within the call  without issue.

The code (Flutter) is similar to this:

Mix in Audio into a valid RTC session, with default settings

```
    final playing = await session.playAudioFile(path, (){
      state = MessagePlayerState.STOPPED;
      if (!disposing) {
        whenFinished();
      }
    });
```

The recording options are as follows (My UID is a hardcoded string, that is not the same as any participant UIDs)

```
    http.Response response = await http.post(
      Uri.https(AGORA_REST_URL, '$AGORA_REST_API_VERSION/$appId/cloud_recording/resourceid/$resourceId/mode/mix/start'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: 'Basic $basicAuth',
        HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
      },
      body: jsonEncode(<String, dynamic>{
        'cname': channelName,
        'uid': uid,
        'clientRequest': {
          'recordingConfig':{
            'channelType':0,
            'streamTypes':2, // TODO: Should be a streamTypes of 0 (audio only), but get failures.
            'audioProfile':1,
            'videoStreamType':0,
            'maxIdleTime':120,
            'transcodingConfig':{
              'width':360,
              'height':640,
              'fps':30,
              'bitrate':600,
              'maxResolutionUid':'1',
              'mixedVideoLayout':1
            },
            'recordingFileConfig':{
              'avFileType': ['hls','mp4']
            }
          },
          'storageConfig':{
            'vendor':1,
            'region':3,
            'bucket':AWS_RECORDING_BUCKET, // TODO: Env Var
            'accessKey':AWS_BUCKET_ACCESS_KEY,
            'secretKey':AWS_BUCKET_SECRET_KEY,
          }
        },
      }),
    );
```

The m3u8 and  ts files are present in the S3 bucket.

Adjusting the metadata tags in S3 results in a file that plays fine in Safari, but no mixed in audio is heard.

Converting the file to aac with ffmpeg shows this error

```
[hls @ 0x7fd6cc808200] Opening '2838cfc6254e9fec2e3088976f39d7ce_bip_20210618014151427.ts' for reading
[mpegts @ 0x7fd6cc00a600] Packet corrupt (stream = 0, dts = 1437390).
size=     480kB time=00:00:30.69 bitrate= 128.1kbits/s speed=1.49e+03x    
video:0kB audio:470kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 2.093976%
```

And the result is the same as from the S3 bucket.

Any help or hints appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This can be closed/ignored. Turns out we had an edge condition that did not show when the app was used normally, but if, for instance, you wanted a very stage managed recording to show off to others it broke.